# Readiness probe failed: remote error: tls: bad certificate

Tags: kubernetes

I get the following error:

```
 Warning  Unhealthy  14m (x4 over 15m)     kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get "https://10.244.1.13:8443/healthz": remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

The server is configured with tls support.

In https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/ it is written that:  `If scheme field is set to HTTPS, the kubelet sends an HTTPS request skipping the certificate verification.` so it is not clear why we get this error.

Answer (score 0):

What you have mentioned in the description is completely different from the subject.
Please check you have configured only in readiness prob and  You need to configure in both readiness and liveness probe.

if you are looking forward to send to the HTTPS request to the service you have to change the scheme.

livenessProbe:

httpGet:

path: /

port: 443

scheme: HTTPS

readinessProbe:

httpGet:

path: /

port: 443

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error the kubelet should be configured with the ca certificate of the server.